# django magic urls for user registration best practices

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

What's the best practice for creating 'magic' url's for user registration in django? Currently we're using [allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) for the user reg part. I'll use groups for the example. You have a group and you want to easily invite new user's to that group. So we're generating a unique string for each group, then a related url for that.

You can then share that url with new people. The intent being they visit that url, end up at the new user registration page. Once they register, they are part of that group.

Is there a best practice for this? I have this built to where we're generating the unique group urls. When a user hits that view, should we store that in the session, hide it in the user reg form etc. PS, I'm not exactly how I would hide and process a hidden form element using allauth.

Answer (score 1):

You could try making a custom adapter & overriding the [`save_user`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/adapter.py#L162) method.

Then you can store the group information in the session, and use it in your custom adapter.

from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

```
class MyAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=True):
        user = super(MyAdapter, self).save_user(request, user, form, commit=commit)
        # do your custom stuff here
        return user
```

And in your settings, add this

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'myapp.adapter.MyAdapter
```